# Is it possible to filter with the condition contains in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with data from column B to F. In the column F I have the data in this format:

```
2
2;4
2;4;8
...
```

I would like to knw if there is some way to filter in VBA to show only the rows that contains 4 in the column F, for example, or the columns that contains 8... and so on.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I am trying to iterate the rows with the data, but when I try to hide a row, I get an error that tells that I can't est the Hidden property of the class Range.

My code is this:

```
Private Sub cmbRevisiones_Change()

    

    Dim miRevision As String
    Dim miUltimaFila As Integer
    
    
    miRevision = "4"
    miUltimaFila = 185
    
    
    For miIterador = 14 To miUltimaFila
    
        Dim misRevisiones As String
        misRevisiones = Me.Cells(miIterador, 6)
        
        If InStr(misRevisiones, miRevision) > 0 Then
            Rows(miIterador).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next miIterador
    
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: on the filter drop down there is a contains, does that not work?

Comment: "contains 4" will also filter 44, 444, etc.  Unless you add leading/trailing `;` then you can filter "contains ;4;"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to do it in VBA.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, in this case no matter, this case will not happen.

Comment: If you want to use VBA then loop over the cells, split on ";" and check the resulting array for "4" - hide the matched rows.  If there's some specific problem you run into while doing that, post back with your code and someone will help.

Comment: @TimWilliams I will try iterating the rows and hide the rows that I don't need according the criteria.

Comment: `Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("B:F")).AutoFilter 5, "*4*"`? Why don't you share the complete code that you've got so far and a screenshot of your data? Surely this can be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub filter()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Set s = ActiveSheet ' work on the active sheet
    'Set s = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'work on a specific sheet
    
    For row = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, ";" & s.Cells(row, "F").Value & ";", ";4;") > 0 Then
        s.Rows(row).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
  
End Sub
```

The key here is the use of the InStr function to see if the value of the cell in column F contains 4.  By looking at a string from the cell in column F with a semicolon prepended and appended, we can look for ";4;" and it will find it even if the 4 is the first or last value in the list.